# Asp.Net Identity usando procedure

Tags: asp.net, identity

Estou precisando da valiosa ajuda de vocês, tenho um projeto web para fazer usando Asp.net e gostaria de usar o Identity para fazer o controle de acesso, usar todos os recursos existentes para fazer o login seguro.

Problema que na base de dados onde o projeto será implantado, apenas é permitido salva e alterar na base usando procedure, teria alguma forma de fazer o identity ser compatível com o uso de procedure?

Answer (score 0):

O identity não seria compatível com essa modo de uso, porem vc pode usar um **EntityFrameWork** para criar o ORM dessa forma. Sendo assim ficaria transparente para você.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim ele geraria para voce o codigo mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este exemplo é feito com uma consulta, mas pode ser feito para save e update.
Segue um link para te ajudar. [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda